# How to get an object from firebase in react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to read object data from firebase, but since I use the code below, some error occurred.

This is my method to read data from firebase.

```
function getMenuData() {
    let newMenu = [];
    MENUref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const menu = {
                id: doc.id,
                Name: doc.data().name,
                desc: doc.data().desc,
                url: Images[doc.data().name],
                people: doc.data().people,
                type: doc.data().type,
                time: doc.data().time,
                ingre: doc.data().ingre,
                season: doc.data().season,
                like: doc.data().like,
            }
            newMenu.push(menu)
        });
        setMenu(newMenu)
        setDisplayOfData(newMenu)
        // console.log('food', Menu)
    });
}
```

Then pop out "Objects are not valid as a React child." error message.
After I do some research shows it need to done through map() method, but can it performed in the "menu: {}" ?

The goal is to read the object data from firebase and make it like this.
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N6Bz.png)

This is my firebase data structure.

[image: My firebase data]

Or some available approaches can do the same thing with the object data like this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Need more information, can you please add more details ?

Comment: I added some description in the body, thanks

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child.` this error generally happens when you try to render an object. Could you share the `render` method you implemented?

Side note but you could call doc.data() just once before building your object.

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript SDK there is something known as useCollectionData than can be imported from `react-firebase-hooks/firestore` then you would use something such as `const [data] = useCollectionData(query);` where query could be a reference to the firebase collection you are pointing to with filtering capabilities ex. `firestore.collection('your-collection').orderBy('createdAt)`. This is the official method of handling firebase data which you can then simply use with the `.map(item => <Item data={item}>)`

Answer (score 0):

Check how your menu is being rendered to the `View`.

Since the menu is an array of data from firebase, to render it to the view, you have to use the map() js method because objects or array cannot be converted to a React Child element.

e.g;

```
{menu.map((item) => {
  return <Text>{item.Name}</Text>
})}
```